# How can I use non-last arg by default, with other non default argue?

Tags: c++, function, arguments

```
#include<iostream>
void f(int a, int b = 2, int c = 3);
int main() {
    f(4);
    //f(4,,5); How can I use second arg by default, with non default third argue?
}
void f(int a, int b ,int c) {
    std::cout << a << '\n' << b << '\n' << c << '\n';
}
```

How can I use non-last arg by default, with other non default argue, in c or c++?

Comment: you can't. .....

Comment: You can't do that in the general case, but you can kind of emulate it with a `f_args` structure https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/GvceYY

Comment: thx I should override the func or do some dark magic things